# How to cite regularly published editorials that have no specific titles?

Tags: publications, citations, citation-style

Many magazines and journals have standard editorial pieces such as a letter from the editor to introduce that month's publication; or closing comments written by different people.

For example, the New Hampshire Review has its "Last Word" column, such as this one: http://www.nhbr.com/June-24-2005/Last-Word/

Notice the entire article is titled "Last Word." There is no subtitle to further identify the article. (This is the case for this particular piece; other "Last Word" columns do have subtitles; so maybe this one is an anomaly.)

Some database aggregators write summaries. In this case, for the above article, the EBSCO title field has "Making history with the 80-20 rule" (see http://connection.ebscohost.com/c/articles/17494538/making-history-80-20-rule)

How do you cite something like this in APA style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Citing editorials, using APA Style, is actually not that difficult. You just have to specify the relevant type of material ("Editorial" or "Letter to the editor") in square brackets and provide the full date of publication. The latter, in combination with the title of the editorial, naturally serves as a unique identifier for the piece (so, no subtitle is needed). For example, for the first source that you have mentioned in your question, I think that the appropriate citation would be the following ([support](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/citation/apa/editorials)):

> Last Word. [Editorial]. (2005, June 24). *New Hampshire Business
>   Review*, p. A1.

In regard to the second source that you have mentioned, I think that you incorrectly refer to the entry as summary. IMHO it is simply a bibliographic entry, referring to the corresponding regular published article. In that case, I would cite the original article and not the EBSCO entry.

Comment: Obviously, you need to replace "A1" with the real page number(s), if known.

Comment: The citation now looks like this: 
  
Reinfeld, H. (2005). Last word - Making history with the 80-20 rule [Editorial]. New Hampshire Business Review, 27(13), 51.  Retrieved from http://www.nhbr.com/
  
It might now be exactly "kosher," but I'm more comfortable because it gives information on how to identify that one is looking at the correct source. 
  
Also, it occurred to me that the lack of a subtitle could be an oversight; i.e., it might appear in print but not online.

Comment: @RJo: The citation looks well. However: 1) neither author, nor subtitle were present via the original URL, so I'm not sure how accurate is that information (even solid databases contain inaccuracies and mistakes); 2) per APA, references to sources, published in newspapers, including editorials and letters to editor, should contain "p. " or "pp. " before actual page identifiers; 3) if you want to add a link to the source, provide full URL to specific source, not to publication's home page; 4) per APA, you should italicize publication name and issue, that is, _New Hampshire Business Review, 27_.